# Django/HTML: Pre-populating "number" input fields with decimal values from a model

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm writing code for editing infos about a product an user has already saved in our database.
So I want to pre-populate the fields of the form with the 'old' infos.

Everything works fine except for the prices that I can't get to be displayed. I understand that the problem is related to the decimals since the "weight" field (whole numbers) works fine.

Here's the context in my view function (working fine, I can print the prices values on the console):

```
context["old_title"] = selected_product.title
    context["old_weight"] = selected_product.weight
    context["old_dayprice"] = selected_product.price_day_tvac
    context["old_weekendprice"] = selected_product.price_weekend_tvac
    context["old_weekprice"] = selected_product.price_week_tvac
    context["old_monthprice"] = selected_product.price_month_tvac
    context["old_description"] = selected_product.text
```

Here's the HTML input:

```
<div class="col-md-3 multi-horizontal" data-for="dayprice">
                  <div class="form-group" data-children-count="1">
                    <label
                      class="form-control-label display-7 font-weight-bold"
                      for="website"
                      >€ / day </label
                    >
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="dayprice"
                      data-form-field="Dayprice"
                      id="dayprice"
                      placeholder="5"
                      step="any"
                      min="0"
                      value= "{{ old_dayprice }}"
                    />
                    <p class="font-italic font-weight-light"></p>
                  </div>
```

and here's the model's concerned fields:

```
price_day_tvac = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="DAY - Medium season", default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
price_week_tvac = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="WEEK - Medium season", default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
price_weekend_tvac = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="WEEKEND - Medium season", default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2
price_month_tvac = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="MONTH - Medium season", default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

I tried changing the 'steps'(do different values, 'any', removing it), placing a hard-coded value (with decimal or not, it works), converting the number in the context to a fload()..

I don't really know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried converting the context into a string? Since you've already tried to convert it to a float.